# write common/generic Unit Tests for all controllers

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, moq

i would like to ask that in web api 2.0 is there is any way that i can write common/generic unit tests for all controllers? 
like i have to test that user is passing valid input to all actions in a controller. so that is going to be one unit test for all actions. is there any way i write only one unit test and use for all actions with-in controller? or if i broader the scope write one unit test that is to be used by all controllers? and similar functionality that is common among multiple controllers, i have to write multiple unit tests in conventional programming but i want to make it efficient.so is there any way to do that?

Comment: _I  have to test that user is passing valid input to all actions in a controller_ - that doesn't sound like a unit test?

Comment: a unit test is supposed to be a single test for a single characteristic. suppose if you have an index action in home controller and it has some beviour like, checking null, then checking that if the user is logged in and then load data, you will have to write 3 unit tests for three of this characteristics.

Comment: those are not unit tests. you're talking about model validation and those are tested with integration tests.